# How to get the root site collection programaticallty via SSON and ECMA?

Tags: javascript, ssom

We have created web application.

Within this we created 2 site collection: 
Site collection 1 - `http://pcname:3333/`

Site collection 2 - `http://pcname:3333/sites/sc2`

Within each site collection we created 3 webs.

1. How to get the root site colelction URL (not root web of sitecollection) via SSOM
2. How to get the root site colelction URL via ECMA (say on masterpage)

Answer (score 1):

Using C# (server-side):

```
SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Web.Site;
var rootSiteCollection = siteCollection.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url;
```

If you have alternate URLs, then use 'AlternateUrls'

On the client side, you could use plain old javascript

```
var winLoc = window.location;
var siteUrl = winLoc.protocol + '//' + winLoc.host + (winLoc.port ? ':' + winLoc.port : '');
window.console && console.log(siteUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, for client javascript, _spPageContextInfo is your friend.

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_spPageContextInfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx